# How does std::vector copy objects to its internal storage

Tags: c++, pointers, free, stdvector

I have the following problem:

```
void add(){
  cRow Row();
  Row.add("Column", "Value");
  std::vector<cRow> mRows;
  mRows.push_back(Row);
}

cRow::cRow(): mCol(NULL), mVal(NULL) {
}

cRow::add(const char* Col, const char* Val){
  mCol = strdup(Col);
  mVal = strdup(Val);
}

cRow::~cRow(){
  free(mCol);
  free(mVal);
}
```

After adding the local variable Row to the vector, the destructor is called for that Row and the strings are freed.

Obviously, the pointers to the strings of the stored row in the vector are now freed as well. Any access to the rows after leaving the local scope will result in segfaults.

The dump of the rows looks after 2 calls like that:

```
| (null) | (null)  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| (null)| (null) |
| LastContainerUpdatePropagation| 1307967498 |
------------------------ END ------------------------
```

after 3 calls:

```
| (null) | (null)  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| (null)| (null) |
| (null)| (null) |
| LastSystemUpdatePropagation| 1307967498 |
------------------------ END ------------------------
```

and after leaving the scope completely without adding a new row, every row was freed.

So, now my question: How does std:vector copy objects? What do I have to do to keep the pointers to the strings or to copy them into another space?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `cRow Row()` does not declare a variable, it declares a function. The code you posted is not real, it won't even compile. Please, post real code.

Comment: Two words: [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::vector` uses the [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) to copy objects. Since you have not defined a copy constructor, it will use the [implicit C++ copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor#Implicit_copy_constructor), which just copies all members recursively; this isn't enough, since you are manually managing memory.

You need to either define your own copy constructor, or use something like `std::string`, which will do the right thing if copied.

As a matter of good practice, any class with a non-trivial destructor should have a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, for precisely this reason (this is known as the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)). If a copy constructor doesn't make sense (eg, for things like `ostream`), it should be made private, in order to prevent accidental copying.

Comment: I would change "non-trivial class" to "class with non-trivial constructor" -- classes can be plenty untrivial and still use implicit copy constructor.

Comment: "*As a matter of good practice, any non-trivial class should have a copy constructor*" I disagree with this whole-heartedly. The vast majority of the time the implicitly-defined copy constructor will be just fine (assuming one writes C++ rather than C-with-classes) and writing your own only introduces the possibility for error.

Comment: @ildjarn : Exactly. Bottom-level classes (the ones that interface with raw types) will usually have explicit copy-constructors etc., but higher-level classes built from them won't normally need any explicitly defined copy constructors at all, despite being non-trivial.

Comment: "any class with a non-trivial destructor should have a copy constructor" and a copy assignment operator. See [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: And probably a `swap` function, which will in any case make the copy assignment operator straightforward.

Comment: @Steve : As well as making the class' move constructor and move-assignment operator completely trivial in the presence of rvalue references.

Comment: That's what I initially expected from std::vector. I implemented now a copy constructor, which also has shown me some leaks at other sites where I also tried to copy rows. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` uses the copy constructor to initialise its elements.  If you haven't written on explicitly, the compiler provides one, but as you are doing memory management, you need to either:

1. Provide a copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor (see the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29))
2. Use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) and create a small wrapper that handles all the memory management for a single value, and use as many of those as required in your `cRow` class (note that you will still need to provide the appropriate copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor for your RAII container).
3. Use a type that handles the memory for you, in your example, you are using `const char*`, which could be replaced with `std::string`, which will handle the memory management.

**Note:** only approach #3 avoids having to write a custom version of the three functions.